# Meaning of ものかわ in a Haiku

Tags: classical-japanese

Bashō:
ふつかよい ものかわはなの あるあいだ.

I’m completely lost by ものかわ. Any idea?

Comment: [古語辞典](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AF)で調べてみたら・・・「もの－かは　分類　連語　取り立てて言うほどではない。ものの数ではない。」だそうです

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original should be:

> 二日酔{ふつかよ}**ひ** ものか**は**花{はな}の あるあ**ひ**だ

The expression in question is 「ものか**は**」 and not 「ものか**わ**」, which would probably be why you could not look it up.

As @Chocolate stated above, 「ものかは」 means **"trivial","trifling","of no significance"**, etc. in Classical Japanese.  It has a nuance similar to that of "**to hell with**" without the vulgarity.

Thus, the haiku means:

***"I won't be bothered with hangovers whilst the flowers are in bloom."***

One final note:

When Japanese people say "while the flowers are in bloom", they are almost always referring to a very short period of time.  That is why we might want to get drunk and not care about it if it were only for a few days.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed a little inconsistency between version about the は/わ but the existence of classical hiragana use made me doubt a lot